# How to add wordpress blog to Windows 2008 R2 site

Tags: wp-admin

One way is to install php and wordpress on server following  [WordPress Windows 2008 Web Server R2 IIS 7.5 setup](http://www.amixa.com/blog/2011/01/07/wordpress-windows-2008-web-server-r2-iis-7-5-setup/). Is it possible to reroute url like blog.yourcompanyname.com to another ip address and use linux host to do job?

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to do this though DNS. If your server has a separate public facing IP address, just add a new record to yourcompanyname.com pointing blog to the IP address.